# Wie heißen einige Onlinebücher für junge Erwachsene?

Tags: learning

Ich suche eine deutsche Geschichte, die ich lesen kann.
Ich habe »[Harry Potter and the Methods of Rationality](http://www.hpmor.com/)«, »[Worm](https://parahumans.wordpress.com/)« und »[Animorphs the Reckoning](https://www.fanfiction.net/s/11090259/1/r-Animorphs-The-Reckoning)« sehr gemocht aber ich kann nichts ähnliches auf Deutsch finden.

Any suggestions would be great - I found a translation of hpmor, but I was hoping for something new.
It should be comprehensible to me (common language, nothing highly technical), but still complex enough to be an interesting story.

Comment: You are looking for *fanfiction deutsch* or *fanfic deutsch*.

Comment: Note that our list of interesting literature is not limited to printed editions but obviuosly people prefer printed editions.